# How to correctly use `strictly` with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

In gradle 6.7.1 I am trying to use [`strictly`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:enforcing_dependency_version) to specify a range of versions for a transitive dependency.

In the documentation linked above, it says

> For example, [...] instead of `strictly 1.0`, that it *strictly depends* on the `[1.0, 2.0[` range, but *prefers* `1.0`.

I am trying what was suggested, where I want to specify a range with a minimum version but no maximum version. I do it as below:

```
def LIB_MIN_VERSION = '2.16.0'

testCompile('some-library') {
  version {
    strictly [LIB_MIN_VERSION,)
  }
}
```

From [the documentation on versioning](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html), `)` means an exclusive bound, and when an upper bound is missing, there is no upper bound.

When I run `./gradlew dependencies`, I get this error:

```
> startup failed:
  build file '/home/shane/src/flink-svc/build.gradle': 119: expecting ']', found ')' @ line 119, column 33.
           strictly [LIB_MIN_VERSION,)
                                     ^
```

If I change to `strictly [LIB_MIN_VERSION,]` and rerun, I instead get this error:

```
> Could not get unknown property 'strictly' for  of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultMutableVersionConstraint.
```

Is it possible this range feature isn't available in my version of gradle? Or am I making a syntax error?

---

I tried @Slaw's suggestion to quote the range as `strictly '[LIB_MIN_VERSION,)'`. When I do, I don't get an error running `./gradlew dependencies`, but in the output the resolution shows as failed:

```
some-library:{strictly [LIB_MIN_VERSION,)} FAILED
```

If I use `strictly LIB_MIN_VERSION` without a range (with is undesirable), then I don't get `FAILED`:

```
some-library:{strictly 2.16.0} -> 2.16.0
```

The dependency resolution also shows as `FAILED` if I try using Groovy string interpolation with `strictly "[${LOG4J_LIB_VERSION},)"`:

```
some-library:{strictly [2.16.0,)} FAILED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (as far as I can tell) was that this syntax was not supported by Gradle 6.7.1. Once I upgraded to 7.0, it worked using Groovy string interpolation, as below:

```
strictly "[${LOG4J_LIB_VERSION},)"
```